# Multilevel foldable content with Jquery in django template

Tags: jquery, django

I have a multilevel (unknown depth) content that I want to serve in Django template. I have the variable {{ source }} that's essentially a list of elements. Each element can be simple ({name:xxx, value:yyy}) or a new container ({name:zzz: members: [another list of elements]})

I'm trying to figure out how to write my jquery and my template to achieve foldable content that will show user
 
`<div class='header'>{{xxx.name}}</div>
<div class='content'>{{xxx.value}}</div>`

I figured that I need to use recursion in template ([like this)](https://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2008/01/22/recursion-in-django-templates/https://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2008/01/22/recursion-in-django-templates/) so I can loop over and over until I reach the bottom of my variable content.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

With jQuery I can probably use thing like to allow unfold/fold back:
`$(".header").click(function(){
    $content = $(this).next('content');
    $content.toggle();
});` 
So I can allow user to show hidden div with class "content" as this class is initially set to be display: none with CSS, everywhere on the page. But I'm failing to figure out how to have this nested structure where upon click user unfolds content of what's inside of that level and show only either member values or new sub-member names (in case if content is another list) and new sub-members become new headers (containers) that are clickable to allow user to unfold additional content inside.

Cheers,
Milos

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question by looking at the code example by Brenden Palmer

HTML

```
    <h1>A Cool Accordion</h1>

<p class="description">
  You could simply toggle the .show class (if display: block is uncommented in the CSS) in JavaScript, but you'll lose the animation.
</p>

<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 1</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 2</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 3</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Open Inner</a>
        <div class="inner">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
            blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Open Inner #2</a>
        <div class="inner">
          <p>
            Children will automatically close upon closing its parent.
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 4</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Technically any number of nested elements</a>
        <ul class="inner">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="toggle">Another nested element</a>
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                As long as the inner element has inner as one of its classes then it will be toggled.
              </p>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
                blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
              </p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>Option 2</li>

      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Open+Sans:300,400,600');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

p {
    font-size:1.1em;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

.description {
  margin: 1em auto 2.25em;
}

body {
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 1.5em auto;
    color: #333;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;

    .inner {
        padding-left: 1em;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: none;

        &.show {
          /*display: block;*/
        }
    }

    li {
        margin: .5em 0;

        a.toggle {
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.78);
            color: #fefefe;
            padding: .75em;
            border-radius: 0.15em;
            transition: background .3s ease;

            &:hover {
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
        $this.next().removeClass('show');
        $this.next().slideUp(350);
    } else {
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
        $this.next().toggleClass('show');
        $this.next().slideToggle(350);
    }
});
```

https://codepen.io/brenden/pen/Kwbpyj